# Passing data to child via @Input vs. retrieving from service or store

Tags: angular

I am wondering about the specific differences between passing data to a child component in Angular via an @Input vs. retrieving that same data via a service or ngrx store.

My specific example involves a parent component that retrieves some data from an API and then stores that in a service (it's only ever retrieved at the initial load). Some of that data needs to be used in child components that are used as form controls (e.g. custom select elements). My instinct is to pass that data via @Input, but I'm not quite clear *why* that's the better option, aside from it being the "Angular way".

I figure the advantages are:

- Eliminating a dependency on the child component
- Keeping the child component unattached to any global state/store makes it more reusable/testable
- Perhaps more readable -- it's more obvious how data is being passed into that component.

Is my assumption correct? Curious to hear some thoughts on the merits of passing data in these different ways in an Angular app. Thank you!

Comment: The reasons you have presented are generally the reasons, but there may be more. If you couple a component to your state, you won't be able to use it in an application that doesn't consume your state.

Comment: I also agree, the reasons you have presented are the main reasons for this. Also worth noting is that components who talk directly to the global state is called container component or smart component, the ones that are isolated and only communicated by '@output' / '@input' are called presentational component or dumb component

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's much less obvious how the data is being passed into the component, or at least figuring out where the data is actually coming from.

It the component is getting it from the store, you go to the store, and you've found the source. The end. If it's any more difficult than that, then the component.ts almost certainly has far too many responsibilities.

If the component is getting it from an @input, then you have to go to the parent and find out where the parent is getting the data. If that also comes from an @input, you then have to go to that component's parent and find out where that parent is getting its data. Eventually, you (hopefully) find it somewhere, which may ultimately be coming from the same store.

THEN, if your original component is reused by other components, you have to follow this same process for each component that's consuming it. Now you've spent 3 hours trying to track down the place the data can come from instead of the 5 seconds of going straight to the store.

VERY generic components should be dumb components. Components that could be part of a separate CSS library. But their immediate parents should be getting their info from the store most of the time.

That's my opinion. A lot of people disagree.